# Error pushing queue.yaml to App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

In latest version of gcloud SDK (0.9.15), which includes gae-python 1.8.9, I can no longer push my queue.yaml to GAE. Executing with:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml mqtt.yaml queue.yaml device.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Error parsing ./queue.yaml: Unexpected attribute 'queue' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
  in "./queue.yaml", line 2, column 1.
```

Contents of queue.yaml:

```
queue:
- name: mqtt
  rate: 10/s

- name: device
  rate: 10/s
```

Not sure what changed. This was working in gae-python 1.8.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to push task-queue config as if it were a module. If you just want to update the queue config, then run `appcfg.py update_queues .`